# Ошибка "Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (9, 50, 50, 3)"

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Я написал нейронную сеть на keras, вот её код:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import np_utils

np.random.seed(4)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()


train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r"D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RedBlueClassification\RedBlueClassification\red_and_blue\train",
    target_size=(50, 50),
    batch_size=9,
    class_mode='binary'
    )

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RedBlueClassification\RedBlueClassification\red_and_blue\validation',
    target_size=(50, 50),
    batch_size=9,
    class_mode='binary'
    )

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RedBlueClassification\RedBlueClassification\red_and_blue\test',
    target_size=(50, 50),
    batch_size=9,
    class_mode='binary'
    )

model = Sequential(name = 'Red and Blue classification')

model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy']
    )

batch_size = 9
nb_train_samples = 18
nb_validation_samples = 4
nb_test_samples = 2

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs = 5,
    validation_data = val_generator,
    validation_steps=2, 
    )

scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)
print("Аккуратность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Но, во время выполнения выходит ошибка:

> Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (9, 50, 50, 3)

Всё, что я нашёл в интернете, это то, что надо написать:

```
TrainX= np.reshape(TrainX,(TrainX.shape[0], 1, TrainX.shape[1]))
```

но это не помогает, так как во первых, программа требует двумерный массив, а во вторых, ей не нравится, что вместо `TrainX` я ставлю генераторы (я не знаю, что еще туда поставить).

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша НС ожидает на входе тензор размерности `(N, 2)`, а получает на вход тензор размерности `(9, 50, 50, 3)`, где `9` - число экземпляров в выборке (в вашем случае это размер `"batch"`).

При задании размерности тензора в модели число экземпляров не задается - задаются все размерности тензора кроме числа экземпляров (изображений). Следовательно в вашем случае архитектура НС будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
model = Sequential(name = 'Red and Blue classification')

model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(50, 50, 3)))
...
```

Т.е. модель ожидает на вход изображения размерности `50x50` с тремя цветовыми каналами `RGB`. Число изображений может меняться поэтому его не задают при создании модели.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде помогло! Но теперь появилась новая ошибка: 'Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (9, 1)' Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать теперь?

Comment: @Artur264, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). StackOverflow работает немного по-другому - вы задаете один конкретный вопрос со всеми деталями и получаете на него ответ(ы). Если у вас возник новый вопрос - откройте новый SO вопрос и укажите в нем всю соответствующую информацию (код, код ошибки и т.д.)